# What are the differences between these types of inclusions/imports?

Tags: javascript, import

```
const { test } = require('@playwright/test'); //note the @symbol
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
import {Blob} from 'buffer';
```

How do these imports differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one with the `@` is a [scoped module](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes). It allows modules with the same name, provided they belong to different scopes.

A good example of when this is useful is when a developer forks a module from another developer, and publishes it to the same registry (e.g. npm). This would allow `@user1/some-module` and `@user2/some-module` instead of a globally-scoped `some-module`. Without scoping, developers would have to either rename their fork to publish it.

The first two use the [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (CJS) syntax, while the third is an [ECMAScript Module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (ESM) syntax. [Both are inter-operable](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs) in Node.js at this point. Only ESM syntax is natively available on the browser, while CJS syntax may require additional tooling to work on a browser.